# How to filter an input to search a database in python

Tags: python, json, database

I'm an intermediate python coder, but i'm still somewhat new to it. I just started using json files (kind of like a database), and my most recent projects was to use the nba database (https://data.nba.net/prod/v1/today.json) for a user input that tells about an nba character that they input in. The problem was that it would pour the entire roster database, so I added a filter. The problem with the filter was that it wouldn't let anything out. If you type Lebron James, shows nothing. Not even an error.

```
from requests import get
from pprint import PrettyPrinter

BASE_URL = "https://data.nba.net"
ALL_JSON = "/prod/v1/today.json"

printer = PrettyPrinter()

data = get(BASE_URL + ALL_JSON).json()

def get_links():
    data = get(BASE_URL + ALL_JSON).json()
    links = data['links']
    return links

def ask_player():
    players = get_links()['leagueRosterPlayers']
    playerselected = get(
        BASE_URL + players).json()['league']['standard']
    
    'topic' == input('Type the player you wish to know more about:')
    
    playerselected = list(filter(lambda x: x['firstName'] == "topic",playerselected ))
    playerselected = list(filter(lambda y: y['lastName'] == "topic",playerselected ))
    
    for standard in playerselected:
        name = standard['firstName']
        name2 = standard['lastName']
        jersey = standard['jersey']
        #teams = standard['teams']
        college = standard['collegeName']
        dob = standard['dateOfBirthUTC']
        years = standard['yearsPro']

        printer.pprint(f"{name} {name2}, jersey number {jersey}, went to {college} college, was born in {dob}, and has been in the nba for {years} full year(s).")

ask_player()
```

My code is above. I tried a lot, and I even read most of the database to see if I missed something. Can someone help? It's a project for fun, by the way.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is around these lines of code where `topic` should be a variable, not a string. Also, you should assign the input to the topic variable, not using `==`.

The filter compares the first name and last name, so we split the input to two parts.

```
topic = input('Type the player you wish to know more about:')
    
firstName = topic.split()[0]
lastName = topic.split()[1]

playerselected = list(filter(lambda x: x['firstName'] == firstName and x['lastName'] == lastName, playerselected ))
```

The output is like this for `Steven Adams`,

```
('Steven Adams, jersey number 4, went to Pittsburgh college, was born in '
 '1993-07-20, and has been in the nba for 8 full year(s).')
```